# Smtp error in sending mails in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to send mail on registration. In my console i am getting as Mail sent. But I am not getting any mail..

My `development.rb` file has:

```
config.cache_classes = false
config.log_level = :debug

# Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
config.whiny_nils = true

# Show full error reports and disable caching
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = true
config.action_view.debug_rjs                         = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching             = false

# Don't care if the mailer can't send
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => "localhost:3000"}
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.default_charset = 'utf-8'

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'gmail.com',
  :user_name            => "mailme@gmail.com",
  :password             => "gmailpwd",
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Please give suggestions why I am not getting mail ??

Comment: Did you check your spam folder?

Comment: Did you finally solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Comment: @gparis-Even  then its not working . WHich is a good way to keep the smtp settings in development.rb or in production.rb file ??

Comment: I think it's OK. But let me ask you another question... which Ruby/Rails versions are you using? Note that Ruby < 1.8.7 and Rails < 2.2 had problems with GMail and you'll need this gem: https://github.com/ambethia/smtp-tls